# Article 'a' altering the meaning of a phrase

Tags: articles

Recently, at work, I had an argument with a colleague on the use of article 'a' in the sentence: "Active i is just 'a' little more than a smaller and cheaper Activa."

In the sentence, he meant that 'Activa i is nothing but a smaller and cheaper version of Activa'. He insists that adding 'just a' to the original sentence has changed the meaning.

I disagree: To me none of the two sentences convey the intended meaning.

Please help me sort out the confusion.

Comment: So this is really about adding "just a", not about adding "a". The title is misleading.

Comment: yeah.. but the key problem is how adding 'a' is changing the meaning... I had no confusion regarding the function of 'just' in the sentence. Thanks for give the post a look though.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 'a' *does* make a difference.

Consider the following sentences:

> I've got a little money.
>   I've got little money.

The first one means that you have a fair amount of money. Not much, but not very little either. However, removing the 'a' makes it the second sentence, which means that you have a less amount of money.

*a little*: a fair amount. Not much, but just enough.
*little*: almost none.

Similarly:
*a few*: a fair amount.
*few*: almost none.

---

> "Activa i is just a little more than a smaller and cheaper Activa."

In this sentence, a little means 'a fair amount'. So it means that Activa i is a bit better than a 'smaller and cheaper Activa'.

However if you remove the 'a', you would get:

> "Activa i is just little more than a smaller and cheaper Activa."

Which means that it is *hardly* better than 'a smaller and cheaper Activa'.

---

Both 'few' and 'little' on their own, are used in negative connotations. It gives a slight negative sound to the sentence.

And you are right; none of the sentences convey the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

One would not typically say "(just) a little more than a smaller and cheaper..." - it should be "(just) a smaller and cheaper...". Note that "just" here diminishes its quality, much like "little more than a...", whereas, "a smaller and cheaper" is a neutral to slightly positive fact that it is smaller and cheaper.

So: It is little more than a smaller and cheaper... = negative

It is just a smaller and cheaper... = slightly negative

or

It is a smaller and cheaper... = neutral/positive